# How can I replace my Ubuntu partition by a Windows partition?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

So, I have a Ubuntu partition on my hard drive and was wondering if i would be able to delete the Ubuntu partition and re-partition it into Windows?

Comment: Create or delete, resize or move, check, label, copy and paste... http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your description is rather vague, you an most definitely accomplish what you want with the `diskpart` utility. Hit **Start** > **Run**, and type `diskpart.exe` before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you then press <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should get a brief introduction to the workings of the program.

If you don't currently have a working Windows install, the Windows setup disks contain tools to partition disks, which should be sufficient for a basic Windows system.

I'm told there are graphical utilities to accomplish the same tasks, these differ greatly in both ability and appearance between Windows versions. There are also a number of third-party tools, both paid, libre, and gratis, that can either be used from inside a Windows login or as a bootable live disk. Your Ubuntu install disk contains a number of options in this regard. I myself am partial to the Gentoo live disks, available [here](http://mirrors.eu.kernel.org/gentoo/releases/amd64/11.2/).

Note that non-Windows-bundled software has historically had troubles resizing (end sometimes moving) NTFS partitions, so you might want to avoid third-party software for these tasks, if they should prove necessary.